# How to sync zimbra calendar with google calendar in both direction

Tags: synchronization, google-api, zimbra

I need to automatically synchronize zimbra calender with my google calender and vise versa. i am planing to develop a desktop application with google calender api , am I going in wrong direction ? if anyone have experience like this kind of synchronization please help me .

Answer (score 1):

I did a manual syncrhonisation between zimbra calendar and sugarcrm calendar using webservices of both products. All the code was written in zimbra only (as a zimlet). In reality, it was not a true syncrhonisation button but rather one export button and one import button that the user had to press. I guess one could easily create one syncrhonisation button that does the two operations serially. You could also make the synchronisation automatic by putting the synchronisation code inside a javascript timer that gets called every user-defined (in the zimlet preferences editor) time period. If google calendar has an API that can speak JSON it should be pretty doable all zimbra-side.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar and ended up implementing it on Google App Engine with Node - took a couple of weekends. I just wanted to see all events in my work calendar (Zimbra) on my personal Google Calendar. I tried forwarding events and I didn't want to share my Zimbra calendar publicly. I took Zimbra's open source Java libraries and wrote up a simple application on Google Cloud and AWS Lambda that copies events from Zimbra to Google and in the other direction. The sync process currently runs on AWS Lambda once an hour. Check it out: https://zimbra-calendar-sync.appspot.com/ and let me know if you have ideas on how to improve it.